# Python Data frame: Create New Sequential Columns Based on a Set of Populated and Null Columns using Sequential If Then Else Logic

Tags: python, if-statement, field, sequence

***Goal: To categorize an ID (row) into top 3 prioritized categories***

I have the following data frame table (white) and I'm trying to create the following columns (highlighted yellow).

[image]

Below is the logic I want to implement in code:

**To fill in 'Cat_Priority_1' column:**

```
    1. If 'Cat_1' is not null, then 'Cat_Priority_1' = the value in 'Cat_1'
    2. If 'Cat_1' is null, then look to see if 'Cat_2' is null
    a. If 'Cat_2' is not null then 'Cat_Priority_1' equals the value in 'Cat_2'
    3. If 'Cat_2' is null then look to see if 'Cat_3' is null
    a. If 'Cat_3' is not null then 'Cat_Priority_1' equals the value in 'Cat_3'
    4. If 'Cat_3' is null, then look to see if 'Cat_4' is null
.... and so on all the way through Cat_6
```

**To fill in 'Cat_Priority_2' column:** this column follows the same logic as 'Cat_Priority_1' EXCEPT 'Cat_Priority_2' cannot equal 'Cat_Priority_1'; please see screen shot of table above for examples

**To fill in 'Cat_Priority_3' column:** this column follows the same logic as 'Cat_Priority_1' EXCEPT 'Cat_Priority_3' cannot equal 'Cat_Priority_1' or 'Cat_Priority_2'; please see screen shot of table above for examples

**Logic Caveat #1:** If Cat_1 through Cat_6 are all 'nan' then 'Cat_Priority_1' equals 'Cat_1', 'Cat_Priority_2' equals 'Cat_2', 'Cat_Priority_3' equals 'Cat_3'

**Logic Caveat #2:** Only two of the columns have values populated --> See row 5 in above table for example

**Logic Caveat #3:** Only one of the columns have values populated --> See row 6 in above table for example

Below is some code I started to try.  Unfortunately, it did not work ... see table output it produced below:

```
df_mock['Prioritize_1'] = df_mock.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!